# VS Code characters fades

Tags: visual-studio-code

After upgrading Visual Studio Code to version 1.23.0 (Windows 10), sometimes characters fades.
I discard a graphical issue because the only window which fades is VS Code window.
You can see an example in the following image (look at main menu, file name or url variable inside the editor):

[image: Example of character fading]

How could I fix this? Any conf variable to tweak? Perhaps a VS Code bug?

Comment: The issue disappears when I hover the mouse over faded characters.

Comment: Opened issue on GitHub: Microsoft/vscode: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49601

Comment: It seems that issue was fixed with VS Code 1.26